# Validate select2 plugin with multiple=true

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to validate select2 plugin with Jquery validation from last few days....it works with sinlge element selection...but when i put multiple="true" it doesn't work.... check here my code...

```
<select name="Class[]" id="Class" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Class 1</option>
    <option value="2">Class 2</option>
</select>
```

Here the field "Class" is using Select2 plugin with multiple="multiple" by using following code:

```
$("#Class").select2();
$('#Class').select2({placeholder: "Select"});
```

It is working fine.
Now i want to validate it using following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input, textarea, select").not('.nostyle').uniform();
$("#FormName").validate({
    ignore: 'input[type="hidden"]',
    rules: {
        Class: {
            required: true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Class: {
            required: "Please select atleast one!!",
        }
    }   
});
});
</script>
```

It is not validating above "class" field!!

Comment: no one is online today???

Answer (score 3):

You can check out this :
There are so many solutions for this :
https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/215

Let me know if it does not work.
Also, http://wangweiqiang.net/how-to-make-jquery-validation-engine-works-well-for-select2/

Comment: please specify the solution along with link

Comment: The first link is broken

Comment: The second is spammy

Answer (score 1):

Below scripts work for me you can try this and save your time:-

**Script:-**

```
$("#addPartnerBranch").validate({
 ignore: [], 
 rules: {
     partner_name: {
         required: true,
         minlength: 4
     },
     "address_emailAddresses[]": { required:true },
     'address_emailAddresses': 'required',
     'address[phoneNumbers][]': 'required',
 },
 submitHandler: function (form) {
    console.log(form);
 }
});
```

**HTML FORM**

```
    <form id="addPartnerBranch" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Partner Branch</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="userProfile-overflowY">         
                <fieldset>
                    <legend id="profileLabel">Branch Detail:</legend>
                    <div class="box-content bordered-all">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input text required"><label for="partner-name">Branch Name *</label><input type="text" name="partner_name" class="form-control input-lg error" required="required" id="partner-name"><label for="partner-name" class="error">This field is required.</label></div>                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="prtnerEmployee">Mail address *</label>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="address[emailAddresses]" value=""><select name="address[emailAddresses][]" multiple="" required="required" class="select2_2 form-control select2-hidden-accessible error" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="">Add email &amp; Enter</option></select><label for="address[emailAddresses][]" class="error">This field is required.</label><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 100px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><ul class="select2-selection__rendered"><li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li></ul></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>                                 </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="prtnerEmployee">Phone number *</label>                                  
                                    <input type="hidden" name="address[phoneNumbers]" value=""><select name="address[phoneNumbers][]" multiple="" required="required" class="select2_2 form-control select2-hidden-accessible error" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="">Add phone &amp; Enter</option></select><label for="address[phoneNumbers][]" class="error">This field is required.</label><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 100px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><ul class="select2-selection__rendered"><li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li></ul></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>                                   </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="prtnerEmployee">Fax number</label>                                  
                                    <input type="hidden" name="address[faxNumbers]" value=""><select name="address[faxNumbers][]" multiple="" class="select2_2 form-control select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="0">Please Add</option></select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 100px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><ul class="select2-selection__rendered"><li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="" style="width: 0.75em;"></li></ul></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>                                 </div>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="55">              <input type="hidden" name="partnerId" id="partnerid" value="1">             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light">ADD</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

[Reference](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/)

Answer (score 0):

Add required to your HTML

```
<select name="Class[]" id="Class" multiple="multiple" required>
```

And do these changes in validator

```
rules: {
    "Class[]": {
        required: true,
    }
},
messages: {
    "Class[]": {
        required: "Please select atleast one!!",
    }
}
```